# VBA Regular Expression - select all italicized text - spaces included

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

So I have the following VB script which wraps each and every italicized word with `<em>` tags. This works fine, I'd just like to extend the RE to find all italicized text together, with spaces, so it wraps the whole section with `<em>` tags, instead of each and every word individually.

I tried adding `" "` and `(\S)` etc. but it still doesn't select the whole string with spaces, but each and every word indiviually.

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Font.Italic = True
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Italic = False
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "([a-zA-Z0-9\:]{1,})"
    .Replacement.Text = "<em>\1</em>"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

**Example text:**

> askdjaksdj kaljdkjsadska *askdjlkdjl aksdjlskjd sakdj sakjdlkjsd askdj
>   alkjd lksadj lsajd lksajd lksaj dlkaj dlksajd lkjs dkl jaks dj*
>   askdljsakdjska djskla djlksa djsadj

**After running original macro:**

```
askdjaksdj kaljdkjsadska <em>askdjlkdjl</em> <em>aksdjlskjd</em> <em>sakdj</em> <em>sakjdlkjsd</em> <em>askdj</em> <em>alkjd</em> <em>lksadj</em> <em>lsajd</em> <em>lksajd</em> <em>lksaj</em> <em>dlkaj</em> <em>dlksajd</em> <em>lkjs</em> <em>dkl</em> <em>jaks</em> <em>dj</em> askdljsakdjska djskla djlksa djsadj
```

Comment: `([a-zA-Z0-9\:\s]+)` try this

Comment: @CodeManiac you mean `([a-zA-Z0-9\:\s]+{1,})`? This doesn't work :/

Comment: `{1,}` is not needed as `+` means the same as `{1,}`

Comment: @CodeManiac Oh I see, thanks. But that doesn't work either.

Comment: check here https://regex101.com/r/4nTS91/1/  it works.

Comment: @CodeManiac have any idea then what I am doing wrong?
https://tinytake.s3.amazonaws.com/pulse/crumbs/attachments/9570246/TinyTake30-12-2018-10-46-38.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.Text = "([a-zA-Z0-9\: ]{1,})"
```

instead of

```
.Text = "([a-zA-Z0-9\:]{1,})
```

Before running the macro:

[image]

After running the macro:

[image]

Macro:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried that (As mention, tried adding `" "`), but it doesn't work. Doesn't find/replace anything.

Comment: Working for me in ms word macro. I have pasted your code and have just changed that line.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work on my end... I have Word 2013.. could that matter?

Comment: Even I am using Word 2013

Comment: Have any idea then what I am doing wrong?
https://tinytake.s3.amazonaws.com/pulse/crumbs/attachments/9570246/TinyTake30-12-2018-10-46-38.mp4

Comment: @Cauthon Looks fine. I have added the snapshot of vba editor with whole code.

Comment: I restarted Word and it suddenly works... weird. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need wildcards or RegEx. Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Text = ""
  .Replacement.Text = "<em>^&</em>"
  .Font.Italic = True
  .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
  .Forward = True
  .Format = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note, too, that nothing need be selected.

Comment: Awesome... changed accordingly.. thanks, that's such a better solution.